# VBA Excel Apply Conditional Format to Cells Based on Unique Values

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to conditionally format a column with each unique value getting its own unique cell background color.  I run a report where we add a Section Description column for sorting purposes.  For visual aid, I'd like to be able to assign a color to each Section Description.

The flow is:

1. Run the Report
2. Section Descriptions are added
3. Run the macro to assign unique colors per section

The issue I have run into is that each time we run the report there might be a different number of section descriptions that are added.  Therefore, I'm not sure how to assign unique colors when there could be anywhere from 3 sections to 20 sections.

My rough idea is as follows:

(a. Remove all conditional formatting from column A)

1. Look through column A (where the descriptions are) and find all of the unique values
2. Paste the unique values in a separate sheet
3. Go through each unique value and assign a color from a group of colors
4. Assign the conditional format to column A on my main sheet based on the assignments from step 3

The other way that this could be done would be to run this process every time a value is changed in column A.

In terms of a color library it might be nice to have more neutral colors that stick out. I don't need bright neon greens and such.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub ColorDescriptions()
'
' ColorDescriptions Macro
'
    Dim Grid As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowGridA As Long

    Set Grid = Sheets("Grid")

' get the last row from column A that has a value
    lastRowGridA = Grid.Range("A" & Grid.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' move values to STORED VALUES

    Range("A6:A" & lastRowGridA).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("STORED VALUES").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

' remove duplicates

ActiveSheet.Range("$F$2:$F$" & lastRowGridA).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

' apply conditional formatting

Dim lastRowSVF As Long
Dim Z As Integer
Set SV = Sheets("STORED VALUES")

lastRowSVF = SV.Range("F" & SV.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Z = 2
Do
Range("G" & Z).Value = Z
Z = Z + 1
Loop Until Z = lastRowSVF + 1


End Sub
```

So right now this is working and I get all of my unique values and I am able to loop through successfully and stop when I get to the last value.  The next step is to replace the...

```
Range("G" & Z).Value = Z
Z = Z + 1
```

...after the Do, to create conditional formatting using the info from the list.

The replacement will use something like:

```
Sheets("Grid").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="='STORED VALUES'!$F$2"
' $F$2 will need to change as we loop through the list
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
'Color will need to change as we loop through the list, I'm guessing I can use
'something like Z to define the color
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("STORED VALUES").Select
Range("F1").Select
```

I think I am close, but I'm just having trouble with the loop.  Once the loop is working, I'd like to be able to tweak the colors that are used also.

The end goal is that after I run the macro, each value in column A in my Grid sheet will have a conditional format based on the unique values in column A.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem at hand, including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Thanks David, I've updated my original post with what I have done so far.

Comment: Do you care what colors are used?

Comment: Also, Step 2 (copy/past & remove duplicates) is unnecessary.

Comment: I would prefer the colors be more lighter and neutral but easy enough to differentiate from each other.

Answer (score 1):

I decided not to do the gradient thing, and instead foudn a function that generates random color values. This is used with the `Interior.ColorIndex` and not the Long color values.

This should get you started:

```
Sub ColorDescriptions()
    Dim Grid As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowGridA As Long
    Dim gridRange As Range
    Dim r As Range 'row iterator
    Dim dictValues As Object 'Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dictColors As Object 'Scripting.Dictionary

    Set Grid = Sheets(2)
    Set dictValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictColors = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set gridRange = Grid.UsedRange.Columns("A:A")
    'I use a scripting dictionary since it only allows unique keys:
    For Each r In gridRange.Cells
        If Not dictValues.Exists(r.Value) Then
            'This dictionary stores what color to use for each key value
            dictValues(r.Value) = intRndColor(dictColors)
            dictColors(dictValues(r.Value) = ""
        End If

        If dictColors.Count <= 56 Then
            r.Interior.ColorIndex = dictValues(r.Value)
        Else:
            MsgBox "Too many unique values to use only 56 color palette"

        End If
    Next
' apply conditional formatting

''' the rest of your code/

End Sub

'modified from
' http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=85809
Function intRndColor(dict)
     'USE - FUNCTION TO PICK RANDOM COLOR, ALSO ALLOWS EXCLUSION OF COLORS YOU DON'T LIKE
    Dim Again As Label
Again:
    intRndColor = Int((50 * Rnd) + 1) 'GENERATE RANDOM IN

    If dict.Exists(intRndColor) Then GoTo Again

    Select Case intRndColor
    Case Is = 0, 1, 3, 21, 35, 36 'COLORS YOU DON'T WANT; Modify as needed
        GoTo Again
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for your help. I've worked around my solution and I'll post the macro tomorrow.  Stackoverflow won't let me post it yet because of my rep level.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks David for your help.  I ended up solving my issue by finding colors I liked and making sure I only used these colors.  I tried assigning random colors but it wasn't feasible.  This method takes only a few colors and assigns them through my descriptors.

```
Sub ColorDescriptions()
'
' ColorDescriptions Macro
'
' Turn Screen flashing off

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim Grid As Worksheet
Dim lastRowGridA As Long

Set Grid = Sheets("Grid")

Sheets("Grid").Select

'Sort everything by Section Description

Rows("5:5").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Grid").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A5"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Grid").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Selection.AutoFilter


' get the last row from column A that has a value
lastRowGridA = Grid.Range("A" & Grid.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' move values to STORED VALUES
Sheets("Grid").Select
Range("A6:A" & lastRowGridA).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("STORED VALUES").Select
Range("F2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

' remove duplicates

ActiveSheet.Range("$F$2:$F$" & lastRowGridA).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

' apply conditional formatting

Dim lastRowSVF As Long
Dim Z As Integer
Dim A As Integer
Dim B As Integer

Set SV = Sheets("STORED VALUES")

lastRowSVF = SV.Range("F" & SV.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Z = 2
A = 11
B = 12

Do

If (Z Mod 8) + 2 = 2 Then
D = A
ElseIf (Z Mod 8) + 2 = 3 Then
D = B
Else: D = (Z Mod 8) + 2
End If

Sheets("Grid").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="='STORED VALUES'!$F$" & Z
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent & D
    .TintAndShade = 0.6
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("STORED VALUES").Select

'This next section is used to document the colors being assigned and the method

Range("G" & Z).Value = Z
Range("H" & Z).Value = "xlThemeColorAccent" & D
Range("I" & Z).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent & D
    .TintAndShade = 0.6
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

Z = Z + 1
Loop Until Z = lastRowSVF + 1


End Sub
```

Comment: This is brilliant work. Just an idea, if you really wanted to do random colours for each cell, I would suggest looking at using RGB codes and then using random integers between 1 & 255 for each. Store each colour code in an array once created then have a loop checking whether the colour code already exists within the array. You can then go back and re-pick the colour if it does or proceed to the next one if it doesn't. You may end up with disgusting colours though ^^.